# Using svn remove - preserve file on disk instead of having it deleted?

Tags: svn

I am creating an eclipse project, which generates a lot of files I don't want to keep under version control. For example, it creates a project folder like:

```
project/
    bin/
      horse.class
      cow.class
    src/
      horse.java
      cow.java
```

so what I do is add the project folder to svn, like:

```
svn add project
```

this puts everything under control, even the bin and .class files. All of those files will have the little 'a' next to them.

How can I simply remove the 'add' status from those files? If I try:

```
svn remove bin/horse.class
```

I have to use the --force option and it deletes the file from disk. Is there a way to simply remove it from source but *not* delete the file from disk?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have a recent version of SVN (at least 1.5), you can use

```
svn remove --keep-local bin/horse.class
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `svn revert` command.

> revert: Restore pristine working copy file (undo most local edits).
>
> usage: revert PATH...

Since your file's pristine state is not-added it should work for you.

```
svn revert bin/horse.class
```

Answer (score 0):

`svn rm --keep-local bin/horse.class` should do the trick, although I would recommend the use of [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). Installation is very simple, and it is much more integrated than the commandline tools (as I'm sure you can imagine).

Comment: hmm I don't think --keep-local is supported by 'standard' svn?: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re08.html It is not mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I would suggest you try out an svn plugin for eclipse, for example: [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

It will automatically only add the correct files for you.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding set up the ignore property of svn to ignore the files you don't want to get added. Look out for the `global-ignores` in the `[miscellany]` section in the subversion configuration file. On Linux this is `~/.subversion/config`, on Windows it's `%USERDIR%\Application Data\Subversion\config`. This however only works for files that you can match with global patterns (like all files ending in `.class` etc).

In the layout shown below I wouldn't simply add `project` but only the files that should get under version control -- assuming that `project/bin/horse.class` is the only file to get omitted you can simply do the add as `svn add --parents project/src; svn add --parents project/bin/cow.class`.